# Cocos2d-x : Socket.io-client-cpp crashes after creating scene

Tags: cocos2d-x, multithreading, socket

I'm using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp with cocos, because the built-in socket.io doesn't support callback (http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/doesnt-work-with-socketio-2-0-1-and-failed-calling-back-with-old-version/37225/3)

Everything is fine, until i want to push new scene after receiving server signal
Here is my code

```
SocIO::SocIO() {

    // client object
    _client = new sio::client();
    _client->connect("ws://localhost:3000");
       ....
       _client->socket()->on("joinedRoom", bind(&SocIO::joinedRoom, this, placeholders::_1));
}


void SocIO::joinedRoom(sio::event &a)
{
    Scene* newScene = PlaygroundScene::createScene(1); // crash on this line
}
```

[image]

I don't know what happened here, didn't get this error with built-in socket.io.
Is it because of threading?